# Mapping Duplicate Zip Codes in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently trying to map zip codes in Tableau Public and have a file of 142 zip codes. However, when mapping in a new spreadsheet, Tableau removes duplicates and only maps unique codes which brings this down to 47 values. How can I get it to map all values regardless of if they are a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds like you use the Dimension "Zip Code" and display it on the map. That will just point out the areas of the zip codes that you provide.

What you want to do is displaying the count of the zip codes, so you can display the amount of each single zip code encoded in colour, size, etc.

Drag and drop the "Zip Code" field to Color or Size in the Marks section on the left. Afterwards right click on it, choose Measure/Count (I used a data set I had available with the top level domains of websites, the outcome however will be the same)
[image]

Afterwards you will have a map displaying how often a certain zip code occured
[image]

If you drag and drop it to Size in the Marks section, you will get circles in the area of the post code, the size of the circle displays how often that post code occurs.

Edit: An alternative that saves you a single mouse click is to drag ZipCode to detail at first (instead of to color or size) and then drag Number of Records to color. That tells Tableau to partition the data by zip code, and then use color to display the Sum(Number of Records) for each zip code.